# Why can't you change argument names in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular, here is the simple example for using $http.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("welcome.htm")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });
});
```

What I don't understand is that $http is the name of the argument in the callback function so why does it make a difference if you rename it to something else?

For example in JavaScript these two are obviously the exact same function

```
function(a, b) {
    return a+b;
}

function(c, d) {
    return c+d;
}
```

But in this case if I replace $http with anything else such as $HTTP it will break?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $HTTP) {
    $HTTP.get("welcome.htm")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: It's angular special behavior, some kind of reflection for argument. by the way, problem when uglify the code. since they are not arguments and are, actually services and factories, you don't need to change them anyway. Angular injects them for you

Comment: Because it is dependency injection...that's what the name of the service is

Comment: Another key difference here is that in angular you can also change the argument order without impacting it `function($http, $scope)` which is not true of your more basic non-angular example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You certainly can use other names, and in specific cases you *should*! Here's how:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", function(thescope, thebackend) {
    thebackend.get("welcome.htm")
      .then(function(response) {
        thescope.myWelcome = response.data;
      });
  }]);
```

Here the second argument for `controller(...)` is an array, with a specific structure.

- In order a list of strings with the names of services you want angular to inject;
- Finally, the last item is your controller constructor function, that takes arguments to be filled with services you asked for earlier in the array.

With this structure you can name the arguments anything you like.

The advantage: you can now minify this code. Minification will leave the strings in the array alone, thus leaving the correct service names for Angular to recognize. The arguments will be safely minified as they can be anything anyways.

The version you had, without such an array, will use the names of arguments to find the appropriate services. If you'd name those arguments differently, Angular would not be able to know what service to inject into that argument.

For quick demo's and adhoc applications your version works fine. This is why you often see it, especially in docs or in SO answers and questions. For production apps I recommend always using the minification-safe version.

[The other answer by @slugonamission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38086113/419956) also has some good nuggets of info, including a link to [the appropriate documentation article on Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

PS. Yes, your second example will break, which you can easily try. There's no way for angular to know what `$HTTP` is, because it only knows about `$http`.

Comment: In your example `$scope.myWelcome` will give an error, as `$scope` is undefined

Comment: so will `$http.get` when you call it `thebackend`

Answer (score 0):

This is called "dependency injection", and there's a large article about it in the [AngularJS manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

In short, Angular needs to know which dependencies your controller has (in your case, `$scope` and `$HTTP`), which it will create for you, and pass into your controller. The default method that it does this is to simply look at the names of your parameters, and infer from that which dependencies you have. If you change, say, `$http` to `$foo`, Angular will no longer know that it needs to inject the `$http` service.

There is an alternative syntax where you can pass in an array to the second parameter of your controller, where the first N element specify the dependencies your controller has (and the ordering), and the final argument is your controller function. It looks something like this:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ["$scope", "$HTTP", function($scope, $HTTP) {
    ...
}]);
```

In this case, you can call the parameters whatever you want; the leading elements in the array specify what the parameters are, so this will still work:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ["$scope", "$HTTP", function($foo, $bar) {
```

And `$foo` will refer to your controller's scope.

Comment: string value needs to match proper service name